# SQL Server display selected Column name as getdate()?

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement here:

```
select 
    sum(CreditValue) as Right(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())), 2)
from
    OrderHeader
```

As you can see, I want to modify the displaying name of the column to the last 2 digits of the year depending on the date of today. However the system keeps telling me this:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Right'. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, STRING, or TEXT_LEX.

Is there anyway to make the query possible to run? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your column name is dynamic, you can try using dyanmic query shown below:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @query = 'select ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SUM(CreditValue)) +' as ' + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Right(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())), 2)) + ''''
from OrderHeader

EXEC(@query)
```